# Making three specific mobs ride each other in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was just wondering how you could make a Pig with a Saddle ride an EnderDragon that is riding a MinecartRideable.

Right now, I have:

```
/summon Pig ~ ~ ~ {Riding:{id:EnderDragon},Saddle:1}
```

and have tried:

```
/summon Pig ~ ~ ~ {Riding:{id:EnderDragon},Riding:{id:MinecartRideable},Saddle:1}
```

Which summons a Pig with a Saddle riding an EnderDragon.

I want it so that the `EnderDragon` is riding a `MinecartRideable`.

Comment: I see you've already answered your own question in this case, but in future there are a range of helpful tools to avoid writing our the whole command yourself. e.g. this one: http://mcstacker.bimbimma.com/

Answer (score 3):

Seeing your two attempts - You almost got it the second time around.

So, your attempt was:

```
/summon Pig ~ ~ ~ {Riding:{id:EnderDragon},Riding:{id:MinecartRideable},Saddle:1}`
```

Right now, your command looks like this:

```
Summon a Pig, riding on a Enderdragon AND a Minecart.
```

---

To make your command correct, you have to nest the mobs correctly:

```
/summon Pig ~ ~ ~ {Riding:{id:EnderDragon,Riding:{id:MinecartRideable}},Saddle:1}
```

Which is:

```
Summon a Pig, riding a Enderdragon that is riding a Minecart.
```

If you want a mob that is riding another mob to ride said mob, you have to nest the `riding` tag inside the second mob.

---

As [stated by MrLemon in an comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/240157/making-three-specific-mobs-ride-each-other-in-minecraft/240158#comment329206_240167), with the `Riding` tag being depreciated and being replaced by the `Passenger` tag (which is basically back-to-front) in the next version of Minecraft (currently active in snapshot 15w41a), we can use:

```
/summon MinecartRideable ~ ~ ~ {Passengers:[{id:EnderDragon,Passengers:[{id:Pig,Saddle:1}]}]}
```

Which is:

```
Summon a Minecart that has a Enderdragon in it which has a pig riding on it.
```

*Or to simply put it: The above stuff but back-to-front.*
Minecart-Enderdragon-Pig, not Pig-Enderdragon-Minecart.

Comment: It is worth noting that starting with 1.9 / 15w41a, `Riding` is deprecated and replaced by `Passengers`, which works the other way around, i.e. summon a Minecart *carrying* and Ender Dragon *carrying* a pig: `/summon MinecartRideable ~ ~ ~ {Passengers:[{id:EnderDragon,Passengers:[{id:Pig,Saddle:1}]}]}` (not 100% sure the tag takes a list of entities (`[]`), but I assume so, since boats can have multiple passengers at the same level).

Comment: @MrLemon At least now, when I plan my stacks - I don't need to flip my lists back to front.

Comment: It's a nice side-effect. The real reason for the change was to allow multiple entities to ride the same entity, which was completely impossible in the previous version of the commands.

Answer (score -3):

You can do that with:

```
/summon Pig ~ ~ ~ {Riding:{id:EnderDragon},Riding:{id:MinecartRideable},Saddle:1}
```

Comment: Care to explain your command? | Also, you've gotten your nestings wrong.